# PDF of human population weight distribution

Tags: r, regression, gamma-distribution

I have a lot of data on human weight coupled with information about gender, age, country and platform (desktop or mobile user). Looking something like this:

```
id, gender, age, country, countryWeight, version, weight, count
...
11, m, 39, HR, 90.7, mobile, 99, 2
12, w, 38, RU, 72.7, desktop, 43, 7
13, w, 13, NL, 72.3, desktop, 57, 71
14, m, 31, PT, 78.7, mobile, 92, 1
15, w, 43, FI, 70.8, mobile, 95, 2
...
```

The countryWeight is a average weight for that gender and country which I found somewhere, so I do not plan to use country.

I would like to compare the distribution of a subset of the data (based on other variable) with an estimated 'expected' distribution based on the subset's composition with regards to gender, age, country and version.

Human weight is not normally distributed. So I tried to fit a log normal distribution but the tails were not looking that good. So I was looking into fitting a gamma distribution. I'm not good with statistics so I felt I better ask someone here if there is a good approach for this. I'm not trying to write a scientific paper, nothing has to be exact and no other number than the n= will be shown. Just nothing poking you in he eye when looking at lines of actual and 'expected' distribution.

So is there a way to use this data to get a normalized probability density function for a given profile (e.g. women, age 34, from US, using desktop)?

I'm using R by the way. And yes the reason I'm asking is that I'm a humble man who do not know what I'm doing.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by "normalizing" your pdf? Why not simply analyze the distribution of human weight as-is?

Comment: Well the thing is that we sometime get into subgroups that are rather small. This means that if I show the actual as-is data it may be that I get a very funny looking curve which I may get into trouble explaining. Maybe the data I have for Swiss male desktop users in the age group 40-50 is mostly heavy people whereas the age 30-40 users are slim people, how do I explain this. My (possibly misguided) idea is that fitting a model would be more conservative, I would get a good looking curve regardless of the size of the subgroup.

Comment: "I would get a **good looking curve** regardless of the size of the subgroup. " I think it would be more accurate to say you would get a "good-looking fiction." Welcome to CV, by the way! Also: what use are you trying to make of these data? What's he story you want to tell (curve aside)?

Comment: Thanks, you sound like my annoying colleague :) There is another variable called 'shop', I'm going to select data for a shop and want to compare its weight distribution to an 'estimated' distribution to find out if the shop's data is from slim or fat people. The problem with just showing data as-is is that where we have little data it looks nothing like a human weight distribution, also sometimes the shop data is so dominant in that group that we are almost comparing it to itself. For height my use of an estimated Gaussian curve worked well, it is frustrating that there is no pdf for weight.

Comment: I *might* be annoying sometimes. :) Are "slim" or "fat" formally defined concepts for your purposes? If they are are, couldn't you just test whether the proportion of thin differs by shop (e.g., using a $\chi^{2}$ contingency-table test)? I do not understand why you want the distribution of weight in shops to look like "a human weight distribution": surely what you want is to compare *actual* distributions among your shops?

Comment: I believe the height and weight distribution of individuals in this population will be shaped the same way as the height and weight distribution of any other human population. That is pretty much a normal curve for height and something not too far from log normal curve for weight. But this has become too complicated so I will use smoothed line of the actual distribution as reference line. Thank you very much for your help and interest.